# How to turn String to String array?

Tags: java

How to write a programme that can store names and id  using `JOptionpane` i tried storing `String` but the result comes up with `String` cannot be converted to `String[]`??

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
public class TestWorker {
public static void main(String args[]) {
 int amount = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "How many Would you like to enter?"));
    String[] storedname = new String[amount];
    storedname = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"Whats the First persons name?");
    Workers(storedname);
}
public static void Workers(String[] Workername){
    System.out.println("The name of the First Worker is " + Workername);

 }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use JOptionPane to input data into an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22801013/how-to-use-joptionpane-to-input-data-into-an-array)

Comment: showInputDialog() allows entering **one** name, and getting back the result, as **one** string. So, since you want N names, you need a loop, asking for one name at each iteration, and storing each of them in the array. You need to read a bit more about loops, and about arrays. The Java tutorial is your friend.

Answer (score 0):

The problem might be with the `Workers` method requiring an input of `String[]` but you are passing it a `String`.

Can you change the `Workers` method to require a `String` instead of a `String[]`, like the example below?

```
public static void Workers(String Workername){



    System.out.println("The name of the First Worker is " + Workername);

 }
```

Answer (score -3):

I could not understand the explanation of your question to be honest. But, I will answer based on the title question. Also, this is a question answered before in another StackOverflow thread. Anyways, you can do it like this:

```
String[] args = "your string".split(" ");
```

You put inside the split method, the string flag that the method will use in order to break the string into string[].

For more info visit: [string to string array conversion in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3413586/string-to-string-array-conversion-in-java)