# How to input user defined (dynamic) data into an array?

Tags: java, arrays, swing, user-input

I've found this Java swing code here, that is said to input data into an array using `JOptionPane`.

The problem is, if I'm not mistaken, that this code just prints out the data iteratively, but there's no array with the data as an output... At least I couldn't print out the 'textfields' array...

The code is here (the last one): [How to use JOptionPane to input data into an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22801013/how-to-use-joptionpane-to-input-data-into-an-array)

Comment: *this code just prints out the data iteratively,.* - so modify the code to add the data to an array and then do whatever you want with array. Rarely will you ever find a code sample that does exactly what you want. Take the time to understand the basics of how the example works and then modify it to do what you want.

Comment: Welcome to SO! When you place a question try to add a minimum content: input sample, expected output sample, what did you try, research and where are you stuck. What did your try? Just copy?

Comment: If the number of datum is not known until indicated by the user (stopping it), it would be necessary to (first) collect the data into a (expandable) list or collection like an `ArrayList`.

Comment: I meen I can output the data to println, but I somehow cannot catch it into an array...  This array public List<JTextField> textfields = new ArrayList<>(OPTIONS);

Comment: thank you, I made it!

class JOptionPaneTest {

    public static final int OPTIONS = 11;
    public static List<JTextField> textfields = new ArrayList<>(OPTIONS);

    //this is my array!
   public static List <String> Acronyms = new ArrayList<>(OPTIONS);

//rest of the code//

if (result == JOptionPane.OK_OPTION) {
            for(JTextField textfield : example.textfields){
             //for (int i=0; i<example.textfields; i++)
                // {
                Acronyms.add(textfield.getText());
                System.out.println(textfield.getText());

            }